# Access Form VBA: how to select all the fields of a section?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my `Access Form` I have 3 sections: `Form Header`, `Detail`, `Form Footer`. Each section has its own fields.

I would like that a button can switch the `Enabled` property of all the fields of the section `Detail`.

I hope that there is a simple string like this, but I really don't know how to do that:

```
Me.<section Detail>.<select all fields into the section>.Enabled = False/True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Me.Detail.Controls` with give you access to all controls of a section, but they don't have a collective Enabled property. You will need to iterate all the controls and, based on their type, set this property to False/True, because not all controls have this property.

Here is an example:

```
For Each ctl In Me.Detail.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
        ctl.Enabled = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: As an alternative in case where you have many types and you don't want to check each type, you can add an `On Error Resume` to ignore any error with setting the `Enabled` property that don't exist on a control. However if you do, please do reset the error handling immediately so you don't hide any other errors that should be bubbled.

Comment: @This I wouldn't use `On Error Resume` - it could hide any real error that occur.  I'd use `ctl.Enabled = Not ctl.Enabled` though - the same procedure will then switch the enabled property whenever it's run.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook That's exactly why I mentioned the need to reset error handling right after. IOW, the instructions would be like `On Error Resume Next`, `ctl.Enabled = Not ctl.Enabled`, `On Error Resume 0`, which means only the statement `ctl.Enabled` is ignored for any kind of errors.

Comment: @This I'd still disagree.  It's a bit like whitewashing to cover any blemishes... and I'm trying to think of any errors that could occur in that one command other than not successfully disabling a control - maybe a text box that should be disabled, but the user is editing the text box when the code runs so it fails where it should have succeeded (just off the top of my head - not sure if that's possible or not).

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say @DarrenBartrup-Cook but I don't buy that argument mainly because this means the loop should never been entered. By the time we encounter that error, we are in a bad state and we might not be able to undo everything, making it even a bigger mess (Incidentally, that would be an argument against using `x = Not x`). In that situation, the best thing would have been to check everything before entering the loop, including validating that the controls' not occupied or forcing the focus to move away.